# If APNs only stores the last push notification per device while offline, why am I receiving all? Working with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a production iOS app that is receiving, in most cases, all the missed push notifications while the device was offline once I connect it again to the Internet. This app uses Firebase Messaging to receive notifications and the default/recommended configuration code in Firebase's docs.

According to Apple, I would only expect only the last notification to arrive:

> Quality of Service, Store-and-Forward, and Coalesced Notifications
> Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS)
> component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts
> to deliver a notification and the destination device is offline, APNs
> stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it
> when the device becomes available again. This component stores only
> the most recent notification per device and per app. If a device is
> offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes
> the previous request to be discarded. If a device remains offline for
> a long time, all its stored notifications in APNs are discarded.
> source: apple push notifications documentation

Is Firebase doing something to ensure notifications delivery? I couldn't find any clear doc about this in the case of iOS.

On the other hand, I am working on a completely new version that uses the same Firebase Instance and client configuration, but this time I only receive the last notification no matter what. This new version is not yet released, so I'm testing it in a debug configuration (the production one is release config).

Not sure what is happening here; it's pretty confusing since the implementations are near identical. Has APNS/Firebase any policy regarding the release config and the QoS? I couldn't find anything related to that...

Thank you in advance!